# How to abort an Ajax request from an Observable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, rxjs, observable

My code contains this simple function I'm using to upload files to my PHP server (there's an `xhr` request nested in an `RxJS/Observable`):

```
fileUpload(file: File): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable( observer => {
        let xhr:XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    observer.next(<any>JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                } else {
                    observer.error(xhr.response);
                    observer.complete();
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.open('POST', '__BACKEND__?action=file-upload', true);
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

It is completely functional but now I would also like to add some sort of a cancellation mechanic to it.

Just unsubscribing from the Observable won't work, because I need to somehow call `xhr.abort()` or I waste precious resources with large uploads.

Is it possible to get an elegant solution by modifying this code or am I doing it wrong because I'm using an `RxJS/Observable` for this task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create an `Observable` you can specify the unsubscribe behavior by returning a `Subscription` or a `function` from builder function:

```
fileUpload(file: File): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable( observer => {
        let xhr:XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    observer.next(<any>JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                    observer.complete();
                } else {
                    observer.error(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.open('POST', '__BACKEND__?action=file-upload', true);
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
        xhr.send(formData);

        //Return the tear down logic. 
        //You may also want to check here that it has not already completed
        //Since this gets called in all cases when the `Subscription` terminates
        return () => xhr.abort();
    });
}
```

Comment: That's the answer I'm looking for, thank you! :) Does this also apply for hot Observables?

Comment: You mean, does the `unsubscribe` logic always get run? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Return the xhr object and execute abort on it in a another observable.

```
var uploadObservable = fileUpload();
var uploadRequest;

uploadObservable.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    uploadRequest = x;
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });


var cancelBtn = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(cancelBtn, 'click');

cancelBtn.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    uploadRequest.abort();
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

Or

```
 fileUpload()
    .flatMap(function(xhr) {
      Rx.Observable.fromEvent(cancelBtn, 'click').subscribe(function() {xhr.abort()})
    })
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer even though it's not exactly an elegant one :) Exposing the xhr object is a bad design practice. There's also no elegant way to attain the xhr object from inside the builder function.

Comment: Suggest you try this out first, your alternative code will not run, you need to change the `subscribe` block to a `finally`

Comment: I also think to use Disposable/Subscription is the right way. However you still need to save some state/var. It would be nice to have a solution without saving any state/vars. To somehow combine the streams. @paulpdaniels I checked my version it should work. Why I would need a finally block?

Comment: Your first example will run, assuming you define the samples. The second example will not because you are returning a `Subscription` object from the `flatMap` which is *not* a supported type. Why do you need external state?

Answer (score 0):

Request will aborted into unsubscribe call.
For more details, see AjaxObservable.unsubscribe sources:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/441d52208df8b9247b01f8ca3993e3a7b0870b10/src/internal/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts#L423