# How to release memory of the responseText in an endless streaming request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, asynchronous, observable

I need to use xmlHTTPRequest to fetch data from an endless motion JPEG data stream, and I heard that a nice trick that the `responseText` can populate data without finishing the request (it will never finish). Now I run into problem.

My request is bind with RxJS observable like this.

```
  postActionGivenDataBinaryStream(url:string, data:string) : Observable<any>{

    this.binary_progress_call_accum = 0 ;
    this.previous_length = 0 ;

    return Observable.create((observer)=>{
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() ;

        xhr.open('POST',url,true) ;
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");
        //this way the binary data keeps populate at state 3
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined');

        xhr.onreadystatechange = () =>{
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    this.binary_progress_call_accum = 0 ;
                    this.previous_length = 0 ;
                    observer.complete();
                } else {
                    this.binary_progress_call_accum = 0 ;
                    this.previous_length = 0 ;
                    observer.error(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.onprogress = (event)=>{
            let outstring:string = "";
            //should preordically emit the response text 

            if (this.binary_progress_call_accum > 1) {
                //just send the next piece of data
                let endCount = xhr.responseText.length ;

                //so here try to next a string

                for (let i = this.previous_length ; i < endCount; ++i ){
                    outstring += ("00" + (xhr.responseText.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2) ;
                }

                observer.next(outstring) ;
                this.previous_length = endCount ;
            }
            else{
                for (let i = 0 ; i < xhr.responseText.length; ++i ){
                    outstring += ("00" + (xhr.responseText.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2) ;
                }
                observer.next(outstring) ;
                this.previous_length = xhr.responseText.length ;
            }

            this.binary_progress_call_accum += 1;
        };

        xhr.send(data) ;

        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/38622923/921082
        //elegantly abort()
        return () => xhr.abort() ;
    }) ;

}
```

But this piece of code has serious problem, I call this observable at a 30 seconds interval, but, it sometimes stuck. When my interval observable triggered, the request just delay for 30 seconds! Without doing anything, the console log gives nothing.

I suspect that it's the xhr.abort() takes too long to finish, before it finishes, the interval observable gives next request, which will conflict with the previous one, which causes the request-response delay. So is there any way to release the memory of `responseText` without using interval to reinit such xhr request observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a tough one, I actually solved it.

The answer has nothing to do with my code above, but the code calls this request observable.

I should use `repeatWhen` instead of `IntervalObservable`. Since `IntervalObservable` doesn't care if the request actually complete or not, it will cause request triggered before last one complete. Whereas `repeatWhen` ensures the last observable actually complete before the next start.

Please check this enlighten discussion, https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/448